# Position search bar from right to left

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm searching to get by search bar that's in a navbar in a dropup menu to go from right to left.
At the moment, my dropup menu is at the far right of my screen just as I want and when I click on my search button, the bar goes off the screen on the right.
I want it to be displayed on the left.

I'm using Bootstrap 5.1

[image: Screenshot]

```css
.btn-group {
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="btn-group dropup">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="material-icons">
      search
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
    </span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <div class="form-outline" id="search">
      <input type="search" id="form1" class="form-control" placeholder="Trouvez une recette!" aria-label="Search" />
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `dropdown-menu-end` on the dropdown element. See [alignment options](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/dropdowns/#alignment-options).

Note that I've corrected your list markup. The only valid child of `ul` is `li`.

```css
.btn-group {
  margin: 150px; /* demo only *
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="btn-group dropup">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="material-icons">
      search
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
    </span>
  </button>

  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end">
    <li>
      <div class="form-outline px-2" id="search">
        <input type="search" id="form1" class="form-control" placeholder="Trouvez une recette!" aria-label="Search" />
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```